# Tengo una trivia, y no se como poner la siguiente pregunta en el mismo html, ya que my onclick lo envio a otro archivo (pregunta2.html)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

esa es solo una pregunta, quiero poder ver la siguiente en el mismo html y no en otro

```js
<script>
            /*ejecuto la primera preguntay las respuestas son dejadas en button para que el usuario solo clickee*/
            document.write ("<strong><h2>¿Quien fue Gabriela Mistral?</strong></h2><br>");
            document.write ("<input type='button' onclick='valor1()' name='r1' id='r1' value='1.- Creadora de la primera vacuna'> <br>");
            document.write ("<input type='button' onclick='valor2()' name='r2' id='r2' value='2.- Poeta y Premio Nobel de Literatura'> <br>");
            document.write ("<input type='button' onclick='valor3()' name='r3' id='r3' value='3.- Cientifica Nuclear'> <br>");
            //creo las funciones que agregaran el puntaje a la respuesta correcta
            var puntaje = 0;
            function valor1() {
                //estos window location envian por metodo get el puntaje a otro html que tiene otra pregunta
                window.location="index2.html?puntaje="+puntaje;
            }
            function valor2() {
                puntaje = puntaje + 10;
                window.location="index2.html?puntaje="+puntaje;
            }
            function valor3() {
                window.location="index2.html?puntaje="+puntaje;
            }
        </script>
```

```html
<script>
            /*ejecuto la primera preguntay las respuestas son dejadas en button para que el usuario solo clickee*/
            doc

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

ument.write ("

### ¿Quien fue Gabriela Mistral?


");
                document.write (" 
");
                document.write (" 
");
                document.write (" 
");
                //creo las funciones que agregaran el puntaje a la respuesta correcta
                var puntaje = 0;
                function valor1() {
                    //estos window location envian por metodo get el puntaje a otro html que tiene otra pregunta
                    window.location="index2.html?puntaje="+puntaje;
                }
                function valor2() {
                    puntaje = puntaje + 10;
                    window.location="index2.html?puntaje="+puntaje;
                }
                function valor3() {
                    window.location="index2.html?puntaje="+puntaje;
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una posible solucion a tu pregunta

Se puede hacer mucho mas eficiente el codigo pero la Hice similar a la logica que estas planteando para que la puedas continuar agregandole mas preguntas faltantes de la trivia.

Si usas `location` estas enviando a otra pagina y si envias a la misma borrarias el contenido de los valores de la puntuacion. Entonces lo que recomiendo es seguir trabajando en la misma pagina y ocultar las preguntas, entonces, cuando aciertes a la respuesta se mostrara el bloque de la siguiente pregunta sumando tambien el puntaje, al final se avisa que se ha terminado las preguntas.

En el codigo no necesitas los id, no lo estas usando, tampoco se necesita usar la etiqueta strong ni br en el h2 porque esa etiqueta hace ambas funciones. se quito los names de los input porque no estas usando un formulario y no envias los datos por submit

Aqui te adjunto el nuevo codigo:

```html
<script>
        // bloque de preguntas 1
        /*ejecuto la primera preguntay las respuestas son dejadas en button para que el usuario solo clickee*/
        document.write ("<h2>¿Quien fue Gabriela Mistral?</h2>");
        document.write ("<input type='button' onclick='valor1()'  value='1.- Creadora de la primera vacuna'> <br>");
        document.write ("<input type='button' onclick='valor2()'  value='2.- Poeta y Premio Nobel de Literatura'> <br>");
        document.write ("<input type='button' onclick='valor3()'  value='3.- Cientifica Nuclear'> <br>");
        //creo las funciones que agregaran el puntaje a la respuesta correcta
       
        // bloque de preguntas 2
        document.write ("<h2 class='p2' style='display:none;'>¿Cuanto es 2 + 2 =?</h2>");
        document.write ("<input class='p2' style='display:none;' type='button' onclick='valor4()'   value='1.- 4'> <br>");
        document.write ("<input class='p2'  style='display:none;' type='button' onclick='valor5()'   value='2.- 3'> <br>");
        document.write ("<input class='p2'  style='display:none;' type='button' onclick='valor6()'   value='3.- 8'> <br>");

         // bloque de preguntas 3
        document.write ("<h2 class='p3' style='display:none;'>¿Que sigue despues de la letra B?</h2>");
        document.write ("<input  class='p3' style='display:none;' type='button' onclick='valor7()'  value='1.- F'> <br>");
        document.write ("<input class='p3'  style='display:none;' type='button' onclick='valor8()'  value='2.- G'> <br>");
        document.write ("<input class='p3'  style='display:none;' type='button' onclick='valor9()'  value='3.- C'> <br>");

        
         // Fin de las preguntas 
         document.write ("<h2 class='fin' style='display:none;'>NO HAY MAS PREGUNTAS, VEA SU RESULTADO</h2>");
        // total de puntaje ganado
        document.write ("<h2>Total de puntuacion: <span id='puntaje'></span></h2>");

        var puntaje = 0; // inicio de puntaje 
   
        // bloque para pregunta 1
       
        function valor2() {
            puntaje = puntaje + 10; // puntaje 
            // mostrar pregunta
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("p2");
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    y[i].style.display= "block";
            }    
            document.getElementById('puntaje').innerHTML=puntaje;
        }

        // bloque para pregunta 2
        function valor4() {
            puntaje = puntaje + 10; // puntaje 
            // mostrar pregunta
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("p3");
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    y[i].style.display= "block";
            }    
           document.getElementById('puntaje').innerHTML=puntaje;
        }


         // bloque para pregunta 3
         function valor9() {
            puntaje = puntaje + 10; // puntaje 
            // no hay mas preguntas que mostrar
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("fin");
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    y[i].style.display= "block";
            }    
           document.getElementById('puntaje').innerHTML=puntaje;
        }

    </script>
```